# Retrieving an object in controller when set hidden in backend TYPO3

Tags: object, typo3, tx-news

I am using the news extension for managing news message for my website. Some of the news items are disabled in the backend. A user has an url with the id of news object and it will trigger an action in my controller

I am trying to get my news object like this

```
$news = $this->newsRepository->findByUid($id);
```

This will return a `NULL` because it's disabled/hidden in the backend. When i switch it back to enable. It will return my object nicely.

I tried it with the following function in my newsRepository

```
public function findHiddenByUid($uid) {

            $query = $this->createQuery();
            $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectSysLanguage(FALSE);   
            $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
            $query->getQuerySettings()->setEnableFieldsToBeIgnored(array('disable')); 
            return $query
            ->matching(
            $query->equals('uid', $uid)
            )
                ->execute()
                ->getFirst();

 }
```

But this will also return a `NULL` .

Is the function wrong, am I missing some settings? I am using TYPO3 7.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `findByUid` I am using in the news extension:

```
public function findByUid($uid, $respectEnableFields = true)
{
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(false);
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectSysLanguage(false);
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setIgnoreEnableFields(!$respectEnableFields);

    return $query->matching(
        $query->logicalAnd(
            $query->equals('uid', $uid),
            $query->equals('deleted', 0)
        ))->execute()->getFirst();
}
```

By calling `->findByUid(123,false)` will also return hidden objects.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work, but it is returning me a queryresult. So when i try to use a setHidden(0) it doesnt work (undefined method) because its not a news model now. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry my fault. I used findById, instead of findByUid. It works! thanks!